# Inconsistent results - Bing Maps API - Geocoding & Plotting using folium

Tags: python, pandas, bing-maps

I am trying to get the co-ordinates and distance but getting inconsistencies from Bing Maps API. Is there something I'm doing wrong or do the responses really vary that much?

**Issue:** The co-ordinates that I get in the JSON response are different for the same starting address.

My input is an excel file with the starting and delivery addresses like so

[image]

```
df = df[['Starting Address', 'Delivery Address', 'Driving Distance (Miles)', 'Radial Distance (Miles)']]

df = df.reset_index()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
#Encoding Addresses
enc_start = urllib.parse.quote(df['Starting Address'][index], safe='')
print(enc_start)
enc_del = urllib.parse.quote(df['Delivery Address'][index], safe='')
print(enc_del)
#API Call
url = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Routes/Driving?wp.0=" + enc_start + "&wp.1=" + enc_del + "&distanceUnit=mi" + "&optmz=distance" + "&key=" + bingMapsKey
response = requests.get(url).json() #Setting API response (JSON)

try:
    s_lat = response["resourceSets"][0]["resources"][0]["bbox"][2] #Fetching Starting Address Latitude
    s_lon = response["resourceSets"][0]["resources"][0]["bbox"][3] #Fetching Starting Address Longitude
    d_lat = response["resourceSets"][0]["resources"][0]["bbox"][0] #Fetching Delivery Address Latitude
    d_lon = response["resourceSets"][0]["resources"][0]["bbox"][1] #Fetching Delivery Address Longitude

    coords_start = (s_lat, s_lon) #Coords of Starting Address
    coords_del = (d_lat, d_lon) #Coords of Delivery Address
    print("c_str ", coords_start)
    print("c_del ", coords_del)

    #Optimized Travel Distance
    travelDistance = response["resourceSets"][0]["resources"][0]["travelDistance"]
    print("travel dist ", travelDistance)
    df.loc[[index], 'Driving Distance (Miles)'] = travelDistance

    # folium.Marker(location=[d_lat, d_lon], popup = df["Delivery Address"][index]).add_to(mc) #Creating Output Map

except:
    IndexError

#Radial Distance
    radialDistance = haversine(coords_start, coords_del, unit=Unit.MILES)
    # # print(radialDistance)
    df.loc[[index], 'Radial Distance (Miles)'] = radialDistance
```

**Output:**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are grabbing the bounding box coordinates rather than at actual starting location. The bounding box is just a recommendation for viewing the full route and would change if both the start and end are not identical between queries.

To get the actual start/end points;

```
s_lat = response["resourceSets"][0]["resources"][0]["routeLegs"][0]["actualStart"]["coordinates"][0]
s_lon = response["resourceSets"][0]["resources"][0]["routeLegs"][0]["actualStart"]["coordinates"][1]
d_lat = response["resourceSets"][0]["resources"][0]["routeLegs"][0]["actualEnd"]["coordinates"][0]
d_lon = response["resourceSets"][0]["resources"][0]["routeLegs"][0]["actualEnd"]["coordinates"][1]
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess for the first few instances, the co-ordinates were matching with the bounding box so it just gave the correct results then.